# React Version Error

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I installed react and react-nom packages to a meteor app. 
the app crashed complaining about the react version + asking for react-addons-transition-group. Right now, here is the installed packages

```
{
  "name": "politicsmeteor",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "simpl-schema": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

Here is the error message

```
WARNING: npm peer requirements (for react-runtime) not installed:
W20180212-22:21:33.054(1)? (STDERR)  - react@16.2.0 installed, react@15.x needed
W20180212-22:21:33.056(1)? (STDERR)  - react-dom@16.2.0 installed, react-dom@15.x needed
W20180212-22:21:33.057(1)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-transition-group@15.x not installed.
W20180212-22:21:33.059(1)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-css-transition-group@15.x not installed.
W20180212-22:21:33.061(1)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-linked-state-mixin@15.x not installed.
W20180212-22:21:33.065(1)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-create-fragment@15.x not installed.
W20180212-22:21:33.068(1)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-update@15.x not installed.
W20180212-22:21:33.070(1)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-test-utils@15.x not installed.
W20180212-22:21:33.072(1)? (STDERR)  - react-addons-perf@15.x not installed.
W20180212-22:21:33.073(1)? (STDERR) 
W20180212-22:21:33.075(1)? (STDERR) Read more about installing npm peer dependencies:
W20180212-22:21:33.077(1)? (STDERR)   http://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies
W20180212-22:21:33.078(1)? (STDERR) 
W20180212-22:21:33.123(1)? (STDERR) /Users/Rumas/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_2.mhhfrm.9045++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20180212-22:21:33.123(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20180212-22:21:33.124(1)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20180212-22:21:33.125(1)? (STDERR) 
W20180212-22:21:33.127(1)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'react-addons-transition-group'
W20180212-22:21:33.129(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
W20180212-22:21:33.131(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.require.resolve (internal/module.js:16:19)
W20180212-22:21:33.133(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.require (/Users/Rumas/Desktop/ReactNative/politics/politicsmeteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:225:32)
W20180212-22:21:33.134(1)? (STDERR)     at makeInstallerOptions.fallback (packages/modules-runtime.js:641:18)
W20180212-22:21:33.135(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:234:16)
W20180212-22:21:33.137(1)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.react-runtime.react-runtime.js (packages/react-runtime/react-runtime.js:29:20)
W20180212-22:21:33.138(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9)
W20180212-22:21:33.140(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16)
W20180212-22:21:33.141(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Rumas/Desktop/ReactNative/politics/politicsmeteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/react-runtime.js:110:15
W20180212-22:21:33.142(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Rumas/Desktop/ReactNative/politics/politicsmeteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/react-runtime.js:123:3
```

I try to install this react-addons-transition-group but it does not change. Plus I don't see why I would need a previous version of React / React-Dom. Any idea ?

Comment: It would be helpful to users on screen readers, search engines, or users who may want to copy/paste stuff into their answer to provide the text, not screenshots, of the error you're seeing.

Comment: Looks like you need to install `react-runtime`. That should install any missing dependencies.

Comment: all of those are warnings (you should update react-runtime if there is any) 

the error is that node does not find react-addons-transition-groups in node modules. Do you have it installed? I dont see it in the dependencies.

Comment: @ceejayoz, you're right! But there is a limitation in the quantity of code I can copy here !

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda, react-runtime seems to be included in the react package, no? I installed it though, but still the error message

Comment: @Nicholas, eact-addons-transition-groups is not installed but this is the first time I see that error, is it a package we should install ?

Comment: The `npm peer requirements not met` warning comes from another Meteor package, that uses [tmeasday:check-npm-versions](https://github.com/tmeasday/check-npm-versions) to soft-bind to these react peer dependencies. Which package is that? (It is not shown on your image, please post the error here as code, and yes this bit of code will not be too long for SO, I've posted way longer logs).

Comment: I just updated the post with the code. I have never heard about this tmeasday package though